# Происходит перенос текста в блоках

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Верстаю страницу и первый блок получается как нужно (2 строки текста), но остальные  переносят его на следующую строку.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как это исправить.
Прикладываю скрины кода html/CSS, также скрины из ИР, и скрин блока макета(как должно быть)[image: HTML][image: CSS][image: ИР_1[![ИР_2[![Макет]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd8GL.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFRRU.jpg)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Просто удаляйте пустое пространство между словами и всё)

Comment: Спасибо большое за негласные правила добавления постов) Я просто совсем профан здесь еще. 
Решил проблему тем, что удалил лишний div services__item
Простите за ваше потраченное время и спасибо вам всем!

Answer (score 3):

Скриншоты не стал рассматривать ...вот так ни чего не переносится так на месте иконки на месте ...так надо было ??

```css
.block {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.items {
  width: 90%;
  max-width:1020px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item div:first-child {
  width: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="block">
  <h2>amazing services</h2>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <div class="fa fa-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>lorem shmorem</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```